# No guarda variable en tiempo de ejecución C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

Tengo un problema con mi proyecto de visual studio,las variables declaradas son las siguientes:

```
 private OPERACION _OPERACION = OPERACION.LISTO; 
 private string funcion = "";
```

Tengo una funcion que me cambia los valores de unas variables globales, es la siguiente:

```
public void cobrar(string cantidad, bool cobroAutomatico)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Entra en cobrar");
        funcion = "cobrar";
        MessageBox.Show("funcion" + funcion);
        _OPERACION = OPERACION.COBRO;
        MessageBox.Show("_OPERACION " + _OPERACION);

        this.cobroAutomatico = cobroAutomatico; 
        cantidadACobrar = cantidad;
        totalIntroducidoFloat = 0;
        //_cobrar();
    }
```

Como veis la variable función y la variable _OPERACION, adquieren nuevos valores, sucesivamente se ejecuta otra funcion cada poco tiempo la cual recoge esas variables globales y dentro de un switch decide que operación hacer dependiendo del valor de estas, la funcion del switch es la siguiente, es algo largo:

```
private bool doPoll()
    {
        if (!hopper.ocupado)
        {
            if (hopperConectado)
            {
                if (!hopper.DoPoll())
                {
                    hopperConectado = false;
                    hopper.SSPComms.CloseComPort();
                    Estadistica.registrarError(hopper.CoinFeeder_Serial_Number + "/" + hopper.Hopper_Serial_Number,
                        Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.CONEXION, Constantes.COMUNIC_MONEDERO);
                    Console.WriteLine("Hopper ha fallado en el doPoll");
                    //Eliminamos las denominaciones de la lista principal para que se dejen de utilizar en las operaciones
                    for (int i = _denominaciones.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                    {
                        ChannelData temp = hopper.UnitDataList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Value == _denominaciones[i].Value);
                        if (temp != null)
                        {
                            _denominaciones.Remove(_denominaciones[i]);
                        }
                    }
                    nivelesActualizados();
                }

            }
            else if (!hopperConectando)
            {
                if (conectarHopper(hopper.CommandStructure.ComPort))
                {
                    Configuracion.recuperarDenoms(_denominaciones);
                    nivelesActualizados();
                }
            }
        }
        if (_modelo == "4bocas")
        {
            foreach (CNV11 nv in nv11s)
            {
                if (!nv.ocupado)
                {
                    if (!nv.DoPoll())
                    {
                        if (nv.Conectado)
                        {
                            nv.Conectado = false;
                            nv.SSPComms.CloseComPort();
                            Console.WriteLine("{0} NV11 ha fallado en el doPoll", nv.CommandStructure.ComPort);
                            Estadistica.registrarError(nv.NV9_Serial_Number + "/" + nv.NoteFloat_Serial_Number,
                                Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.CONEXION, Constantes.COMUNIC_BILLETERO);
                            //Eliminamos las denominaciones de la lista principal para que se dejen de utilizar en las operaciones
                            for (int i = _denominaciones.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                            {
                                ChannelData temp = nv.UnitDataList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Value == _denominaciones[i].Value);
                                if (temp != null)
                                {
                                    _denominaciones.Remove(_denominaciones[i]);
                                }
                            }
                            nivelesActualizados();
                        }
                        if (!nv.Conectando)
                        {
                            if (conectarNV11(payout.CommandStructure.ComPort))
                                nivelesActualizados();
                        }

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (_modelo == "1boca")
        {
            if (!payout.ocupado)
            {
                if (!payout.DoPoll())
                {
                    if (payoutConectado)
                    {
                        payoutConectado = false;
                        payout.SSPComms.CloseComPort();
                        Console.WriteLine("Payout ha fallado en el doPoll");
                        Estadistica.registrarError(payout.NV200_Serial_Number + "/" + payout.Payout_Serial_Number,
                            Estadistica.Error_Item.CODIGO.CONEXION, Constantes.COMUNIC_BILLETERO);
                        //Eliminamos las denominaciones de la lista principal para que se dejen de utilizar en las operaciones
                        for (int i = _denominaciones.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                        {
                            ChannelData temp = payout.UnitDataList.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Value == _denominaciones[i].Value);
                            if (temp != null)
                            {
                                _denominaciones.Remove(_denominaciones[i]);
                            }
                        }
                        nivelesActualizados();
                    }
                    //return false;
                    if (!payoutConectando)
                    {
                        if (conectarPayout(payout.CommandStructure.ComPort))
                            nivelesActualizados();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        tabletCont++;
        if (tabletCont > 12)
        {
            tabletCont = 0;
            if (!display.conectado && !display.conectando)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                {
                    display.Conectar();
                });
                t.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                //Thread t = new Thread(() =>
                //{
                display.doPoll();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(display.serial) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(datosDisplay.sn))
                {
                    datosDisplay.sn = display.serial;
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(display.appVersion) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(datosDisplay.app_version))
                {
                    datosDisplay.app_version = display.appVersion;
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(display.androidVersion) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(datosDisplay.android_version))
                {
                    datosDisplay.android_version = display.androidVersion;
                }
                if (!display.actualizando && datosDisplay.app_version_int > 0)
                {
                    display.actualizando = true;
                    if (Updates.hayActualizacionDisplay(numSerie))
                    {
                        display.actualizarSoftware();
                    }
                }
                //});
                //t.Start();
            }
        }
        switch (funcion)
        {
            case "recaudacionTotal":
                _recaudacionTotal();
                break;
            case "recaudacionParcial":
                _recaudacionParcial();
                break;
            case "recaudacionMonedas":
                _recaudacionMonedas();
                break;
            case "recaudacionBilletes":
                _recaudacionBilletes();
                break;
            case "recaudacionPorDenominacion":
                _recaudacionPorDenominacion();
                break;
            case "rellenarCajon":
                _rellenarCajon();
                break;
            case "pararRellenado":
                _pararRellenado();
                break;
            case "desactivar":
                _desactivar();
                break;
            case "pagar":
                _pagar();
                break;
            case "pagarPorDenominaciones":
                _pagarPorDenominaciones();
                break;
            case "cobrar":
                _cobrar();
                break;
            case "devolverDineroIntroducido":
                _devolverDineroIntroducido();
                break;
            default:
                //funcion = "";
                //Console.WriteLine("Funcion " + funcion + " no reconocida.");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

El metodo con el timer creo que es el siguiente:

```
 private void PollTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool ok = false;
        doPollThread = new Thread(() => ok = doPoll());
        doPollThread.Start();
        doPollThread.Join();
        if (!ok)
        {
            /*
            Console.WriteLine("Error conexion " + contErrores);
            contErrores++;
            if (contErrores > 3)
            {
                contErrores = 0;
                Desconectar();
                cajonConectado = false;
                error(0); // Si falla el doPoll y no se consigue reconectar se lanza el evento error.
            }*/
        }
        else
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("doPoll ok " + DateTime.Now);
        }
        //Cada 30 ciclos actualizamos el XML y la BBDD con los ciclos
        if (ciclosCompletos >= 10)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Se han completado {0} ciclos. Actualizando...", ciclosCompletos);
            ciclosCompletos = 0;
            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                ControlCiclos.procesarDatos(datosCiclos, true);
            });
            t.Start();
            //t.Join();
        }
    }
```

Segun esta ejecución, al cambiar el valor de la variable a cobrar se ejecutaria el metodo _cobrar, pero durante la ejecución del programa estas variables no cambian al pasar por el primer método, ¿alguna sugerencia sobre lo que está ocurriendo?

Un saludo.

Comment: Deberías añadir el código que falta para saber como estan declaradas las variables globales y como se van ejecutando los métodos para poder ver y analizar que puede estar fallando.

Comment: Las variables siempre cambian cuando las asignas algo. O tienes algun problema con el ámbito de `funcion`, o se está modificando en otro lugar (no es mala idea que uses siempre `this.`).

Comment: Adhiero a lo que dice Marc, por otro lado, te recomiendo que uses un [enum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/enum) para lo que haces en lugar de hardcodear un `string` que suele ser mala idea..

Comment: Acabo de ver la edición que hiciste y eso no parecen variables globales..

Comment: No estan desclaradas como variables globales pero cumplen la función de ellas, este proyecto es una replica de uno similar pero adaptado a otro programa y el original funciona de esta forma, la adaptación que se esta realizando deberia ser igual con las variables declaradas de la misma forma

Comment: en la primer parte del codigo el metodo se llama `cobrar()` pero en el switch se llama `_cobrar()`, estas seguro que es el mismo metodo? porque uno tiene un `_` en su nombre

Comment: Si, al principio entra en el metodo cobrar y este modifica las variables, luego entra en otro metodo recogiendo estas variables y lanza el metodo _cobrar, son 2 metodos distintos

Comment: Te aconsejo que crees un [mcve] para que podamos probarlo. Estoy casi seguro que en el proceso de crearlo, es posible que tu mismo te des cuenta de tu error

Comment: El proyecto el cual se esta trabajando es muy extenso y un tanto complicado de explicar, en pocas palabras seria cambiar una variable en tiempo de ejecucion para que un metodo que se ejecuta con un timer las coja y a traves de un switch cuyo parametro es una de estas varaibles se ejecute

Comment: he puesto varios mensajes de log, para controlar las variables constantemente, en el metodo que las cambia, estas cambian bien, pero a la hora de ejecutar el metodo que se ejecuta con un timer cada poco tiempo las variables no han cambiado para este metodo.

Comment: ¿cual es la funcion en donde se encuentra el switch? ¿puedes poner el codigo completo?

Comment: Esto parece un problema de entornos de variables. Donde esta declarado cada una de esas cosas? si esos valores no cambian es porque no son la misma variable. Decis que usas un timer para cambiar algo, pero no especificas que cosa. Eso tambien deberiamos verlo.

Comment: de casualidad ejecutas ese metodo con un timer usando thread ? porque entre hilos las variables no se comparten, o al menos no deberian hacerlo por problema de concurrencia

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por las aportaciones, he editado la pregunta con el metodo que creo que es el timer y el metodo que ejecuta ese timer, Leandro podrias explicarme mas sobre lo de que a traves de hilos las variables no se comparten? porque es justo lo que usamos, hilos en este caso y no se como poder guardar las variables en tiempo de ejecucion para usarlas en otro sitio

Comment: "*Tengo una funcion que me cambia los valores de unas variables globales*" llegados a ese punto, no he leído más. Rediseña el código para no usar variables globales, serás una persona más feliz y longeva.

Comment: has pensado en mandar el comando como parámetro a `doPoll`?

Comment: ¿Por qué no mejor declaras como `static` las dos variables que mencionas? Así te desligas de cualquier contexto y siempre apuntarás a la misma memoria simplemente detallando `NombreDeTuClase._OPERACION`.

Comment: Finalmente hemos conseguido que funcione, replicando y adaptando el codigo al programa de destino, el problema venia de una case la cual se renombro y causaba fallo con sucesivas clases, un saludo a todos.